# When targeting multiple class with JQuery, is `each()` mandatory? Best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery

When targeting multiple class with JQuery, is `each()` mandatory ?

With a practical example, this `$('.myClass').html('Hello');` and this `$('.myClass').each( function() { $(this).html('Hello'); };` have, at first glance, the same outcome. I would tend to think that using `each()` to target multiple class is best practice but am I wrong?

Comment: It's necessary sometimes, unnecessary others. It depends on what you're doing and what particular APIs allow. There is no single "best practice".

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, do you want to add that as answer so i can close it?

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate but I can never find one, so yea I'll make it an answer.

Comment: I looked for a duplicate before, there is only me to think of stuff like that Kappa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, a basic design goal was to do as much iteration *implicitly* as possible. So, if you want to add a class to all elements with another class,

```
$(".some-class").addClass("another-class");
```

is all you need. Internally, it effectively does `.each()` for you. It's a matter of opinion, but it would be silly to explicitly use `.each()` for something like that.

In other cases, it depends on exactly what you're doing. Clearly `.each()` is called for when you have a significant or "interesting" amount of work to do for each element in a jQuery object. Some APIs allow a function to be passed and performs an implicit iteration that basically is again like `.each()`; others do not, however.

So it depends on the situation. Note that another possibility is to create your own jQuery method that perform the iteration internally to your own specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: `$('.myClass').html('Hello');`

If you want to apply same function on every myClass element then Case 1 is proper. It is also good practice.

If you want to use DOM Object iteratively then you should use .each method.
Case 2:

```
$( ".myClass" ).each(function( i ) {
    if ( this.style.color !== "blue" ) {
      this.style.color = "blue";
    } else {
      this.style.color = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, so there is no real best practice, like @Pointy said, pretty much depends on the situation

Comment: Yes true. If you want to apply same thing then first is good and if you want to use as iteration then second is good.

Comment: @Hiral your particular example could just be written: $( ".myClass" ).toggleClass('blue');

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule is that if you are changing all by a fixed value, use the short notation.

If you need a dynamic change which will vary from element to element and / or is dependent on the index of the element or some property of the element affected you will have to use `each` with a function.

You can then get the index by declaring one argument to the passed function, which will get the value of the index of that element in the loop, or address the element itself inside the function using the variable `this`, or (if for example, you are passing an arrow function where `this` doesn't work) by declaring two arguments and the second will refer to the element.